# Error installing FIELDimageR in R

Tags: raster, r, rstudio

I am trying to install the FIELDimageR library, I follow the recommendations indicated on
[Github](https://github.com/OpenDroneMap/FIELDimageR#instal), I have tried to install it in the three ways indicated in the install section:

form 1

```
install.packages("FIELDimageR")
```

form 2

```
devtools::install_github("filipematias23/FIELDimageR")
```

form 3

```
setwd("I:/Datos_R/Demo/y2023L/ConteoPlantasR")  
unzip("FIELDimageR-master.zip") 
file.rename("FIELDimageR-master", "FIELDimageR")
shell("R CMD build FIELDimageR")
install.packages("FIELDimageR_0.3.3.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

However, and none have worked for me, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

The version of R that I am using is the following:
[image: version]

I have also tried the recommendations in this link: About the FIELDimageR category, but nothing has worked.

If someone has already gone through this problem and put it to a solution and could help me please, since I have not found the solution.

Comment: Please paste the error message as text. The link for recommendation is not working. Edit the question.

Comment: The error in your screenshot is because you need to install the dependencies before installing from source. However, the `devtools::install_github(...)` method (2) should get dependencies and work, but you don't show how this has failed. Please edit the Q and show how each of your tries actually fails, preferably with text rather than screenshots.

Comment: R 4.0.0 is now over 3 years old and you should try and upgrade first.

Comment: Spaceman sorry for answering until now, what I did was install the most current version of R, and with this command line devtools::install_github(...), it worked without problem.